# Different behavior of using taskset to run processes on isolated CPUs in Linux X86

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, scheduler

I am running a performance test where a group of processes/threads are put into a set of isolated CPUs in Linux.
Let me use /usr/bin/stress as an example to show the different behavior in Linux 4.18.20.
There are 16 CPUs in system, and CPU 2-13 are isolated with isolcpus=2-13.
Test 1, taskset -c 2-13 /usr/bin/stress -c 12. The goal is to run 12 stress instances in CPU 2-13. But in fact, all the stress instances are put on in CPU2, not to other CPUs.

Test 2, taskset -c 2-13 chrt -f 1 /usr/bin/stress -c 12. This time, the 12 instances are put into 12 CPUs, each instance is on a specific CPU.

So the question is why test 1 and 2 got the different behavior, which part of kernel causes this difference ?

#### A demo codes with 2 pthreads.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

pthread_t thread1, thread2;

// Thread function for thread 1
void* thread1Function(void* arg)
{
    printf("Thread 1: Running\n");
    while (1) {
        sleep(1);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

// Thread function for thread 2
void* thread2Function(void* arg)
{
    printf("Thread 2: Running\n");

    // Infinite loop to keep the thread alive
    while (1) {
        sleep(1);
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // Create thread 1
    if (pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, thread1Function, NULL) != 0) {
        printf("Error creating thread 1\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Create thread 2
    if (pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, thread2Function, NULL) != 0) {
        printf("Error creating thread 2\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Wait for both threads to finish
    pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread2, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which CPU runs a task is determined by the scheduler.

Comment: @stark not necessarily, you can use [`sched_setaffinity`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_setaffinity.2.html) to force a certain CPU (or a set of CPUs), that's what the `taskset` command does.

Comment: Yes, sched_setaffinity can assign a process to a set of CPUs to run.  But back to my specific case, I don't know which part of kernel code make the difference. Test 1 is using CFS scheduling, Test 2 is using RT scheduling. But I need to find out the details of root cause.

Answer (score 0):

isolcpus and taskset do not always respect the provided CPU ranges. Each thread of your process requires explicit management.

From this blog - https://chronicle.software/chronicle-tune-your-cpu/
"For example, when you use taskset or sched_setaffinity to specify a range of allowed CPUs for a pinned process, only the first CPU in the allowed range is utilised, regardless of the number of threads in the process."

To get around this I tried to set all threads of my process to RT priority and they got evenly placed after running the process with the taskset command which is the same behavior you see with chrt command.

Comment: Per your discription, I suspected it is what `taskset` is designed to. It does what it is told to do, and it is NOT balancing workload.   So I did not get your point of `getting around this`, did you use taskset and then set all threads to RT pritority, or you just set all threads to RT priority without using taskset?

Comment: I set all threads to RT priority programmatically and also used taskset to choose the CPUs to assign the load on.

i.e taskset -c 0-3 ./test

All threads of 'test' have RT priority set via 

 ` struct sched_param params;
  params.sched_priority = 99;
  const auto prioRes = pthread_setschedparam(pthread_self(), SCHED_FIFO, &params);.`

Comment: I just repeated my tests on an embedded Linux system (5.10.24, with 2 CPU cores). I created 2 pthreads to loop in `sleep(1)`, then I started them with `taskset 3 ./mytest &` and `taskset 3 chrt -f 50 ./mytest &`, I got the same results. That is each thread is running in one core, they are NOT being put/scheduled in one core.